# Transaction not working with aspnetusers table in .net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, transactionscope, distributed-transactions

I want to implement transaction with Asp.net core Identity tables.

After get execute `_userManager.CreateAsync` method data get saved in `AspnetUser` table but in other table data does not save without call `identitydbContextTransaction.Commit()`.

I'm using constructor DI

```
private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext;
    /// <summary>
    /// AccountController Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userManager"></param>
    /// <param name="roleManager"></param>
    /// <param name="signInManager"></param>
    public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
    {
        this.applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]AccountBindingViewModel model)
    {

       using (IDbContextTransaction identitydbContextTransaction = applicationDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
       {
          applicationDbContext.Add(new Users() { Name = "Rishi" });
          applicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
          var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber };
          var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
          if (result.Succeeded)
          {
              ApplicationUser savedUser = _userManager.Users.Where(u => u.Email.Equals(model.Email, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
              if (savedUser != null)
              {
                  SaveEntity(savedUser, model); // Save data in other table
                  throw new Exception();
                  identitydbContextTransaction.Commit();
              }
         }
    }
}
```

This is my `ConfigureServices` method in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.  
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
            // Configure the context to use Microsoft SQL Server  
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration["ConnectionStrings:IdentityConnection"]);

        },ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```

Comment: does `applicationDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()` works with asp.net core 2.0 identity tables